# btcrecover for monero?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

Recently I forgot my password to dogecoin wallet and brute force it with btcrecover (github.com/gurnec/btcrecover), which support bitcoin and many altcoins. Although only around 20 words give me something like 6 mln combinations, I found my password in about half an hour.

Is there something similar exist, planned, or possible for monero to brute force password or seed, in case I forgot some words or correct sequence?

Comment: 20 words gives you 2.43 quadrillion combos. 25 words gives you 1.55 septillion. If I try to go through that many combos on my laptop it crashes. What kind of password did you recover? How many characters long was it?

Comment: The above comment assumes you know all the words of the seed but not the correct order. I could not edit my comment.

Answer (score 4):

BtcRecover is for cases where you already know most of your password or seed. If you don't remember nothing of your password or seed, this program is useless. Even all the supercomputers in the world couldn't brute force a Monero seed or correctly created password.

Answer (score 2):

Generalize this created a challenge to find ONE word in a mnemonic seed.

The winner, amustafa, created a post detailing how he was able to do it. Be sure to check the comments to understand why it would be impossible to brute force a full mnemonic seed.

[Recovering an Incomplete Monero Mnemonic Wallet](https://steemit.com/monero/@amustafa/recovering-an-incomplete-monero-mnemonic-wallet) (link to steemit.com)